# Area over a Curve

Tags: fill

I want to fill the area OVER the curve:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\draw[->,line width = 1pt] (0,0) -- (6,0);
\draw[color=black] (6.3,0) node { $x_1$};
\draw[->,line width = 1pt] (0,0) -- (0,6);
\draw[color=black] (0,6.2) node  { $x_2$};
\draw[color=red,line width = 1pt,smooth,samples=1000,domain=0.8333:6] plot(\x,{5/\x})
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! A very basic variant:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\draw[->,line width = 1pt] (0,0) -- (6,0);
\draw[color=black] (6.3,0) node { $x_1$};
\draw[->,line width = 1pt] (0,0) -- (0,6);
\draw[color=black] (0,6.2) node  { $x_2$};
\path[pattern=north east lines]
    plot[smooth,samples=101,domain=0.8333:6] (\x,{5/\x}) |- cycle;
\draw[color=red,line width = 1pt]
    plot[smooth,samples=101,domain=0.8333:6] (\x,{5/\x});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An arguably better variant might be

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=Triangle]
\draw[<->,line width = 1pt]  (6,0) node[right]{$x_1$}
    -| (0,6) node[above]{$x_2$};
\path[fill=blue!40]
    plot[smooth,samples=101,domain=0.8333:6] (\x,{5/\x}) |- cycle;
\draw[color=red,line width = 1pt]
    plot[smooth,samples=101,domain=0.8333:6] (\x,{5/\x});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly in the direction i thought about. But one thing: Can you hold it as easy as it is now and fill the area with for example blue color

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the immediate help!

Comment: @EricBarbarian Sure. You only need to replace `pattern=north east lines` by `fill=blue`. I added an example.

Comment: One more Question: What has to be the code if i want to fill the area on the other side of the curve?

Comment: @EricBarbarian E.g. `\path[fill=red!40]
    plot[smooth,samples=101,domain=0.8333:6] (\x,{5/\x})|- (0,0) |- cycle;`. You might want to put it before drawing the axes.
`

Comment: Wow, it's so easy when you got it ;) Thanks

Comment: @EricBarbarian schrodinger s cat is a fantastic pedagogue. You'll probably find all the ressources you need in his (numerous) previous posts.